# Dim background like when alertView pops up

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, alertview

I have a tableview that shows up when I push a button. This tableview is added on top of my other UITableview. What I want to do now is when the tableview shows up. My background view is dimmed like when an alertview pops up. You can see an example over here.

I've tried this in code but it doesn't work.

```
_tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5];
```

[image]

Comment: Dont make your _tableView alpha set to .5, Instead first add a UIView with alpha 0.5 to your parent tableview and then add your another table to parent tableView. Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just adding answer with more description that my comment.

Say your Background tableView is `_tableView` and your pop up small tableView `is _tableViewSmall`

1. Create a `UIView` having same height and width as of `_tableView`. Do `addSubView` on your `_tableView`.
   `yourView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5];`
2. Now add your `_tableViewSmall` doing `addSubView` on `_tableView`.

Hope this steps helps you to make it..

Answer (score 4):

try this...

```
yourView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
yourView.alpha = 0.40;
```

Comment: Nice and simple. Best answer

Answer (score 0):

Make a blank black uiview on top of your table view and set its alpha as needed 
in the storyboard.KEEP IT HIDDEN.
When alertview pops up show the view.